# How can I find the limit of a multivariable function?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm a student that start learning Calculus 3 and I came across this problem:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\log\left(x^2+2^{y^2}\right)} {\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}}$$

I need to find the limit. I've tried approaching the origin from the $x$ and $y$ axis:

- Approaching from the $x$ axis:

$$\lim_{(x,0)\to (0,0)}\frac{\log\left(x^2+1\right)} {\sqrt{x^2}}$$

Use the L'Hopital's rule:

$$\lim_{(x,0)\to (0,0)}\frac{\frac{2x}{x^2+1}} {\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2}}}=\lim_{(x,0)\to (0,0)}\frac{2\sqrt{x^2}}{x^2+1}=0$$

- Approaching from $y$ axis and use L'Hopital's rule i got:

$$\lim_{(0,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\log\left(2^{y^2}\right)} {\sqrt{4y^2}}=\lim_{(0,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\frac{y^2\,2^{y^2-1}}{2^{y^2}}} {\frac{8y}{2\sqrt{4y^2}}}=\lim_{(0,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2^{y^2-1}2\sqrt{4y^2}}{16y}=\pm \frac18$$

This would mean that the limit doesn't exist.

But I'm not so sure about the the way I've handled this problem so can you tell me if I made a mistake somewhere and is there another way to solve problem like this one?

Comment: Derivative of $2^{y^2}$ is not  $y^2\;2^{y^2-1}$. You should incorporate your answer as a text here.

Comment: You ca simply use that $\log 2^{y^2} =y^2\log 2$ therefore the limit is zero also for $x=0$. We can'y conclude anything in this way.

Comment: Your post is unreadable. Please don't rely on images. Learn to [type math](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) + [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit along both axis is $0$ but this allows no conclusion.

Instead, let $t=x^2+y^2$ and $f(t)=\log\left(t+2^t\right).$ Then, as $t\to0^+,$ $\frac{f(t)}t\to f'(0)\in\Bbb R,$ so that
$$0\le\frac{\log\left(x^2+2^{y^2}\right)} {\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}}\le \frac{f(t)}{\sqrt t}\sim\sqrt tf'(0)$$
and by the squeeze theorem, your limit is $0.$

Answer (score 1):

As noticed, for the case $x=0$ derivative of $2^{y^2}$ is not $y^2\;2^{y^2-1}$ we can instead use that $\log 2^{y^2} =y^2\log 2$ and also the limit along $y$ axis is zero. This means that in this way we can't conclude anything.

To proceed for a solution we can use that
$$\frac{\log\left(x^2+2^{y^2}\right)} {\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}}=\frac{\log 2^{y^2}+\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2^{y^2}}\right)} {\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}}=\frac{y^2\log 2+\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2^{y^2}}\right)} {\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}}$$

To conclude and show that limit exists, we can bound the numerator using that $\log(1+t)\le t$ as $t \to 0$ and $2^{y^2}>1$, to obtain

$$\frac{y^2\log 2+\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2^{y^2}}\right)} {\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}} \le \frac{x^2+4y^2} {\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}}=\sqrt{x^2+4y^2}\to 0$$